# I can push .Net Core C# nuget package to private github package registry but can't access it from other projects

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2022, http-status-code-401, github-package-registry

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11. I manage to authenticate and push a .Net Core C# package to private gthub package registry but when I try to browse and install that same package from the same private registry in another VS 2022 solution, I get 401. I have added the registry information in VS2022 NuGet Package Manager.

There was a pop up in VS2022 prompting me to auth with github packages when I added the registry. I have also added the info in `nuget.config` at the root of my `.sln` and/or `.csproj` folder. No fxxking Azure please!?!

Comment: You need to provide some more information. How are you authenticating? How did you add your private repo configuration, through a nuget.config file? If this is Azure DevOps Artifacts, did you install the Artifacts Credential Provider? Can you please put some more context with your question, we can only guess from what you've written.

Answer (score 0):

I use command line `dotnet nuget add source ...`, close and restart VS2022 and the problem seems to go away.